# For which rational coefficients is $a+b\alpha+c\alpha^2+d\alpha^3+e\alpha^4$ constructible, where $\alpha=3^{1/5}$?

Tags: number-theory, field-theory, galois-theory, geometric-construction

> Let be $\alpha=3^{1/5}$, and be $\gamma$ the number
> $$
> \gamma=a+b\alpha+c\alpha^2+d\alpha^3+e\alpha^4
> $$
> with $a,b,c,d,e \in \mathbb{Q}$ . For which $a,b,c,d,e \in \mathbb{Q}$ is $\gamma$ constructible?

I know the field of constructible numbers is closed by square roots and the Wantzel theorem for constructibility, but I didn't get anywhere.

Any hint?

Comment: So "constructible" here is in the sense of straightedge & compasses?  So, start with $\mathbb Q$ and successively append squareroots?  I added tag `galois-theory`.

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number $\gamma$ lives in the field $\Bbb Q(\alpha)$, which is a degree $5$ extension of $\Bbb Q$.

If $\gamma$ is constructible, then the extension $\Bbb Q(\gamma)/\Bbb Q$ must have [power-of-two degree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_number#Algebraic_properties).

But this degree should also be a factor of $5$, as $\Bbb Q(\gamma)/\Bbb Q$ is a subextension of $\Bbb Q(\alpha)/\Bbb Q$.

Therefore the only possibility is that the degree is equal to $1$, i.e. $\gamma \in \Bbb Q$. This again is equivalent to $b = c = d = e = 0$, as $1, \alpha,\dots, \alpha^4$ form a $\Bbb Q$-basis of $\Bbb Q(\alpha)/\Bbb Q$.

Answer (score 0):

Let me give a hint, using numbers having the form $a+b\sqrt[3]2+c\sqrt[3]4$, with $a,b,c\in\mathbb{Q}$.  Whatever irreducible polynomial with rational coefficients has this root, will have a set of three conjugate roots including the given one ($\omega=$ a non-real cube root of unity):

$r_1=a+b\sqrt[3]2+c\sqrt[3]4$

$r_2=a+b\omega\sqrt[3]2+c\omega^2\sqrt[3]4$

$r_3=a+b\omega^2\sqrt[3]2+c\omega\sqrt[3]4$

and these would also be constructible.  But the combination

$r_1+\omega^2r_2+\omega r_3=3b\sqrt[3]2$

would also be constructible, which might pose a minor problem unless $b=0$.  A similar contradiction using the combination $r_1+\omega r_2+\omega^2r_3$ similarly forces $c=0$, and so the only constructible blnumvers contained in my set are just the rational numbers.

Now try a similar method with your numbers.  All complex fifth roots of unity, like the cube roots of unity described above, are constructible.